# Get gstreamer pipeline object pointer in source code

Tags: gstreamer, embedded-linux, gstreamer-1.0

I am running below gstreamer command for live streaming:
`gst-launch-1.0 imxv4l2videosrc device=/dev/video0 fps-n=30 imx-capture-mode=0 ! textoverlay name=overlay text=\"Overlay text here\" valignment=top halignment=left font-desc=\"Sans, 22\"! gdkpixbufoverlay name=imageoverlay  location=/home/user/LZ_50/CamOverlay.png ! imxg2dvideotransform ! imxg2dvideosink framebuffer=/dev/fb1 use-vsync=true sync=false"`

I want to change the text overlay dynamic in the GStreamer pipeline.
How can I get the pipeline object pointer to change the text overlay dynamic?

Thank

Comment: You need to write your own GStreamer application..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had written an application but I have an issue with crashing the application using the GStreamer pipeline with overlay image & text.

Finally got the issue of crashing the application.more detail can be found at : [imx Gstreamer plugins](https://github.com/Freescale/gstreamer-imx/issues/272#issuecomment-685683537) .

This also helps to reduce CPU usage(almost 20% 1 core).